# Use app.response to obtain text and then append to text from another field

Tags: javascript, acrobat

All,
I have been trying to figure this out for a few days now, but to no avail.

I am trying to use a check mark as the trigger to first ask the user to input some text, and then "concatenate" that text with the text from a previous text field.

I can copy the text form one field to the other, but can not figure out how to incorporate the app.response part of the goal.

Any help would be appreciated

here is what I am using currently and it is located in Actions as a "Mouse up - Run a Javascript"

```
var fFrom = this.getField("MOB Address");
var fTo = this.getField("Relative");
if(event.target.value=="Off"){
fTo.readonly=false;
fto.value="";
}else{
fTo.readonly=true;
fTo.value=fFrom.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

The return value from app.response is the entered text. You'd use it like this where your field is named "foo"...

```
var responseText = app.response({
    cQuestion: "How are you today?",
    cTitle: "Your Health Status",
    cDefault: "Fine",
    cLabel: "Response:"
});
if (responseText != null) {
    var originalValue = this.getField("foo").value;
    this.getField("foo").value = originalValue + " " + responseText;
}
```

The text entered into the response dialog will get appended to the end of any text already in the "foo" field. I'm not sure how you want that added to your code above but hat's how it's used.

Answer (score 0):

Joel,
OK...I have it working, and I thik I understand what you did. I had tried something similar, but couldn't get it to work for some reason.

Anyway...my question now is...since I am using a checkmark field as the trigger for this action, how can I build in code so that this only happens when the checkmark is clicked to "true" or "Yes"? I would also like to clear the receiving field if the checkmark is unchecked or set to "False" or "Null".

As it stands, anytime you click the checkmark field to mark is checked or unchecked, it runs the code.

Here is what I ended up with:

```
var cRes = app.response({cQuestion: "Enter Nearest Relative First and Last          name:", cTitle: "Nearest Relative", cDefault: "", cLabel: "Response:"
});
if(cRes != null){
var fFrom = this.getField("MOB Address").value;
this.getField("Relative").value = cRes + "\r" + fFrom;
}
```

I tried integrating my original code with this, but...couldn't get it to work.
Again...thanks for your help!